# How to debug a "Wiggle" in a menu in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

I have to debug a menu that "Wiggles" when the user mouses over each element in it. This only happens in Internet Explorer. In other browsers if I'm looking at markup it will update as events are triggered or styles applied and you can see that in the style trace. IE does not do this, if it can I'm unaware. Is there any way to see updates to the styles/markup in explore, live in the markup/style view, while interacting with the page?

Comment: Could you post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: Hit [F12](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: F12 only opens up the debugger. The HTML view will not refresh unless you press the refresh button in the debugger. Ironically its the same key to refresh the entire page... and problems ensue.

Comment: You can also 'refresh' the HTML view with a mouse click to the little blue up and down arrows in the HTML tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was that the menu items would "wiggle" when the user would mouse over each item. The problem was that this only happened in Internet Explorer. Where other browsers will let you watch a "live" view of the markup and styles, IE only allows you to refresh that view by clicking on a button above the view or using F5. That complicates things because if your moused over the browser F5 will reload the page. While if you mouse out and refresh the menu item has lost it's change by the time you click the refresh button.

My solution was to isolate the functions called by the mouseover and mouseout events, which were 7 character dynamically named garbage. Once I had what they were being called I could call them and trigger the mouse over and out actions on my own. Then I was able to refresh the markup view and see the styles, applied styles, that were changing.

Turned out that the on mouse-over event added a style that stripped the padding on the top and bottom of the element. In every other browser the box model is rendered so that this didn't matter. In IE it meant that everything would "wiggle" as you moved though the menu.

Gotta love legacy code... and IE.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very much like an old white-space bug.  Is the menu formed from the Unordered List?  If so, do you have carriage returned between each list item (ie each <li></li> is on a separate line)?

If so, try removing all the whitespace (so all list items are on a single line).

Comment: That's a good suggestion. This happened to me on another project and it's not usual the first thing i think of.